# PHP-FPM-like running of Ruby Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, php

PHP has PHP-FPM, a pool of PHP processes that run, are managed, go away and respawn, etc.
This pool can be used for a bunch of different applications across a system. You set up nginx with a virtual host and tell it to forward `*.php` requests on a particular port (or unix socket), and the worker handles the rest.

It is really, **really** useful when you're on a resource-constrained box running a lot of little apps that aren't used frequently.

I have not seen anything like this for Ruby, in that Rails takes a while to start and is a self-contained app that runs, rather than PHP was has one or more arbitrary entry points in the form of files that you can throw at it.

**Am I correct in my assumption that you can't do the FPM-style app free-for-all with Ruby?**

*(I am aware of Heroku and already use it for side-projects, but I'm more interested in learning more how things work under the covers.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more looking:

From what I can tell, the closest equivalent is [Phusion Passenger (set up with Nginx)](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html), which spools up workers for apps as they're requested (or in advance if needed), and then killed off after a configurable idle period.

Close Enough (tm). :-)

Comment: In lieu of an answer from anyone that isn't me, I'll accept this one for the moment. :-|